# Class std::locale has no member "imbue"

Tags: c++, delimiter

I tried to implement functionality so  `"-"` character to be treated as whitespace when inputting with >> operator in c++.

A tutorial I read said that I could use the "`imbue()`" method to do that, but in Visual Studio I'm getting the error that `std::locale` doesn't have the member `imbue`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
   // Create a custom locale that treats the "-" character as whitespace
   std::locale custom_locale;
   custom_locale.imbue(locale(), new ctype<char>{ 0, 0, 0, 0, " -" });

   // Read a string from the user, using the custom locale
   std::string input;
   std::cin.imbue(custom_locale);
   std::cin >> input;

   // Print the input string
   std::cout << input << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `imbue` is a method of `std::stream` (`std::ios_base` actually) and not `std::locale`. What tutorial tells you otherwise? You might be looking for `use_facet` instead.

Comment: the dreaded "chat g_p_t" told me that. I guess this is a chink in its armor

Comment: Check out cppreference.com, your expectations (and perhaps the tutorial) are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

imbue() was removed from std::locale in C++11. You can create a default global local, then use cin.imbue() and cout.imbue().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
  // Create a default global locale
  std::locale global_locale(std::locale::global(std::locale("")));

  // Create a new locale based on the default global locale
  std::locale custom_locale(global_locale);

  // Read a string from the user, using the custom locale
  std::string input;
  std::cin.imbue(custom_locale);
  std::cin >> input;

  // Print the input string
  std::cout.imbue(custom_locale);
  std::cout << input << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting the error "no instance of constructor "std::locale::locale" matches the argument list.

Comment: I've updated my answer to properly create the locale, and to use imbue() on cin and cout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `imbue` has never been a member of `std::locale`, it wasn't removed in c++11 it's always been in `std::ios_base`

Answer (score 0):

The `std::locale` does not have `imbue()`. You need to use `std::locale` constructure.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

Also, the `std::ctype <char>` object is created incorrectly. Please refer below links and **examples** within them.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char/ctype
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char

Here is my solution. Below code treats `'-'` as whitespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <vector>

// This ctype facet classifies - as whitespace
struct custom_whitespace : std::ctype<char> {
static const mask* make_table()
{
    // make a copy of the "C" locale table
    static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        v['-'] |= space;  // '-' will be classified as whitespace
        v[' '] &= ~space;      // space will not be classified as whitespace
        return &v[0];
    }
    custom_whitespace(std::size_t refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(), false, refs) {}
};

int main()
{
    // Create a custom locale that treats the "-" character as whitespace
    // Create a custom locale that treats the "-" character as whitespace
    std::locale custom_locale(std::locale(), new custom_whitespace);

    // Read a string from the user, using the custom locale
    std::string input;
    std::cin.imbue(custom_locale);
    std::cin >> input;

    // Print the input string
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Alan Birtles, thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer.